# Probability of Two Random Variables in Continuous Uniform Distribution

Tags: probability

If given a continuous uniform distribution between a and b, what is the probability that random varaible $X_1$ is bigger another random variable than $X_2$?

Intuitively either $X_1>X_2$ or $X_1<X_2$. No chance $X_1=X_2$ because continuous distribution. And since both equally likely, $P(X_1>X_2)$ would just be $1/2$.

That make sense but how do you show this mathematically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument from symmetry is perfectly reasonable, and agrees with the result of integration.

For two random variables, $X,Y$ with *independent* and *identical* continuous uniform distributions over interval $(a;b)$ then :

$${\mathsf P(X<Y)~{=~\int_a^b\int_a^y \dfrac{1}{(b-a)^2}~\mathrm d x~\mathrm d y \\=~\dfrac 12}}$$